# Using Atlas from scipy

Tags: ubuntu, python, libraries

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. I need to work with python and scipy, I installed them and when I run the test:

```
python -c "import scipy; scipy.test()"
```

I get the message:

> ImportError: libatlas.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However, I have libatlas libraries installed under the directory `/usr/lib/atlas-base`. I know I can copy the files directly under `/usr/lib`, but I wonder how I could setup the scipy to use the libraries from `usr/lib/atlas-base`?

Comment: Please do not cross post.

Comment: Ok, removed now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't have to copy anything anywhere.

You should add the atlas libraries to the list of locations `ld` will search.

In directory `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` you can add the file `atlas-lib.conf`. This file should contain the directory of `libatlas.so.3gf`, which is `/usr/lib/atlas-base`.

You can do this by running

```
echo "/usr/lib/atlas-base" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/atlas-lib.conf
```

Finally run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

to update `ld` so that it knows about this new file.

Alternatively you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the path to the library when you run and it should be available within SciPy.

Comment: I am not sure whether the atlas-lib.conf was of help, but the LD_LIBRARY_PATH made the trick.

Comment: @lmsasu When you create that file you will need to run `sudo ldconfig` to make it active

Comment: If you don't have root access, what would be the best approach? If you would do it with `virtualenv`, how would you do in that case?

Comment: @Albert Using `virtualenv` is a completely separate subject but without root access you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in an appropriate manner which is mentioned in the answer.

Comment: This sort of thing should be handled by either numpy/scipy or libatlas-dev packages, no? I have an interesting situation where system numpy 1.9.1 works fine, but numpy 1.9.2 in a virtualenv exhibits this problem. Anyway, your solution fixed it. thx.

Answer (score 1):

For me, using a virtualenv, `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/atlas-base/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` at the end of my `.bashrc` file fixed it.